# R bookdown - custom title page

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

How to customize title page using bookdown?

I tried using the following code in the YAML header.

```
includes:
  in_header: preamble.tex
  before_body: body.tex
```

The body.tex file was something pretty simple, just for test:

```
\begin{titlepage}
Hello world
\end{titlepage}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up editing the `_output.yml` file to reference a copy of `default-1.17.0.2.tex` template in my R project directory using yaml template tag.

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">A Minimal Book Example</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
    edit: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo/edit/master/%s
    download: ["pdf", "epub"]
bookdown::pdf_book:
    fig_caption: true
    number_sections: yes
    includes:
        in_header: preamble.tex
    latex_engine: xelatex
    citation_package: natbib
    keep_tex: yes
    template: template.tex
bookdown::epub_book: default
```

For some reason i had an error compiling the pdf (! Undefined control sequence...)  so I included a latex command `\usepackage{graphicx}` in `template.tex` to fix it. Now it is supposed that I am free to customize title page and whatsoever.

Comment: where did you save the `template.tex` file?  and did you create your own template?

Comment: This was helpful to me: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-template.html and https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/templates/default.latex

Answer (score 12):

In the LaTeX template `<R-Library>/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex` we see

```
\begin{document}
$if(title)$
\maketitle
$endif$
$if(abstract)$
\begin{abstract}
$abstract$
\end{abstract}
$endif$

$for(include-before)$
$include-before$
```

This means that a titlepage is created using `\maketitle` if a `title` is defined in the YAML headers. Similar for the `abstract`. If you remove both these tags from your YAML headers, then the content from the file `body.tex` will be the first to be processed and you are free to customize your titlepage there.

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963505/coverpage-and-copyright-notice-before-title-in-r-bookdown) for an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks Ralf for putting me on the track.  I could not make it work properly and I was also looking for a more flexible solution.

Comment: @user1591727 You are welcome. If you found my answer helpful, you might consider up-voting it.