# How do I insert a logo before the document title?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

I would like the logo that I'm inserting in my document to appear before the document title. How do I achieve this?

Here is my preamble:

```
---
title: My Document Title
author:
date:
output: pdf_document
toc: false
geometry: left=0.3in, top=0.3in, right=0.3in, bottom=0.5in
fontsize: 12pt
classoption: portrait, onecolumn
---
```

and the knitr chuck I am inserting the logo with:

````
```{r, out.width = "400px", fig.align = "center", echo=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("path/imagename.png")
```
````

As it is, the title appears first, then the logo.

Comment: If you're trying to output to PDF, you probably have to do this with Latex, commands. You might be better off looking at https://tex.stackexchange.com, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207647/move-logo-higher-above-the-title

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433243/r-bookdown-custom-title-page